# Showing YES or NO instead of 1 and 0 in a php table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have an SQL table where I've got various checkboxes and when displaying them in a view, the values are shown as `0` and `1`. I know that `0` is `false` and `1` is `true`, but the user may not... is there any way to make this show as yes or no?

Here is my table code:

```html
<tbody>
    @foreach ($survey as $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$data->satisfied}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->would_recommend}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Use ternary operator like `{{$data->satisfied ? 'YES : 'NO'}}`

Comment: i added this and it worked

Comment: === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No'

Comment: ahh i see, okay i shall do that

Comment: Still no need to compare with 1. If the value is not 0 or empty string, it is true.

Comment: Since the data comes the DB, you might have to convert it first to int (`intval`) before using the ternary, depending on its type... (or do `== 1`, not `=== 1`)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in the SQL query itself.

Like this:

```
SELECT would_recommend, 
    CASE
        WHEN `satisfied` = '1' THEN 'YES' 
        WHEN `satisfied` = '0' THEN 'NO'
    END
FROM orders;
```

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer. See you now.

Comment: Presentation of data shouldn't be done in the data layer.

Comment: Write in more detail.